# Triangle Inequality for Angles in Projective Space

Tags: metric-spaces, inner-products, projective-geometry, projective-space, angle

I want to show that the angle between two lines through the origin in a (complex or real) inner product vector space $(V,\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ is a distance function which turns $\mathbb{P}V$, the projective space of $V$ (the lines through the origin), into a metric space. I found this post ([metric and measure on the projective space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421735/metric-and-measure-on-the-projective-space)) in which they say this is in fact a distance, but no reference is given. I also found a this link ([Triangle inequality for angles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639135/triangle-inequality-for-angles)), which is for $\mathbb{R}^3$, but the answer is kind of confusing and it is not appropriate for the complex case, I believe.

I understand the angle between two lines $l,l'$ through the origin as the the number
$$\sphericalangle(l,l') := \cos^{-1} \left(\frac{|\langle v,v'\rangle|}{|v||v'|} \right),$$
in which $v \in l$, $v' \in l'$. This does not depend on the choice of $v,v'$, and they can in fact be chosen such that $|v|=|v'|=1$.

The first two properties of distances are pretty easy, so I just need to show the triangle inequality. For three lines $l,l',l''$, we must show that
$$\sphericalangle(l,l'') \leq \sphericalangle(l,l') + \sphericalangle(l',l''),$$
For $v \in l$, $v' \in l'$, $v'' \in l''$, that is
$$\cos^{-1} \left(\frac{|\langle v,v''\rangle|}{|v||v''|} \right) \leq \cos^{-1} \left(\frac{|\langle v,v'\rangle|}{|v||v'|} \right) + \cos^{-1} \left(\frac{|\langle v',v''\rangle|}{|v'||v''|} \right)$$

What I have so far is similar to what is explained in the second link above. I projected $v'$ in the subspace spanned by $v$ and $v''$, to get the vector $w$. Therefore I must prove that

1. $\cos^{-1} \left(\frac{|\langle v,w\rangle|}{|v||w|} \right) \leq \cos^{-1} \left(\frac{|\langle v,v'\rangle|}{|v||v'|} \right)$. For this one, I wish to use the fact that $\cos^{-1}\colon [0,1] \to [0,\pi/2]$ is decreasing, so I must prove that
   $$\frac{|\langle v,w\rangle|}{|v||w|} \geq \frac{|\langle v,v'\rangle|}{|v||v'|};$$
2. The triangle inequality holds for $v,w,v''$, which are coplanar.

I would like some tips on how to proceed on both items, and any additional commentary would be awesome. I would also like to know if this is true for infinite dimensional $V$, and a proof that does not use a basis would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For real vector spaces, this is the triangle inequality for the triangles on the sphere. The proof can be found in Bridson & Haefliger's book "Metric spaces of non-positive curvature", Theorem I.2.3, which is deduced there from the "spherical law of cosines". I reproduce their reasoning as follows.

Let $\Delta$ be a spherical triangle (on a sphere of radius $1$) with vertices $A,B,C$, and let $a=\sphericalangle(B,C)$, $b=\sphericalangle(C,A)$, $c=\sphericalangle(A,B)$, and $\gamma$ denote the vertex angle at $C$ (on the sphere itself). Then the spherical law of cosines reads
$$
\cos c = \cos a\cos b + \sin a\sin b\cos\gamma
$$
Thus, as $\gamma$ varies from $0$ to $\pi$, $\cos c$ varies from $\cos(b-a)$ to $\cos(b+a)$. In particular, $\cos c$ is always $\ge$ than $\cos(b+a)$. Since $\cos$ is decreasing, we get $c\le b+a$.